# Derivative of a function where $y$ is implicit function of $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

So I have an equation that determines y implicitly as function of $x$. My job is to find $y''(0)$

The equation is
$$
 \ln(1+y)+\sin(xy)=\ln(5)
$$
What I've tried doing is just raising everything as a power of eulers number, so i can cancel the ln terms.

Therefore I'm left with
$$
 1+y+e^{\sin(xy)}=5 
$$
which then gives that
$$
y=4-e^{\sin(xy)}
$$
I then take and differentiate twice and input $y''(0)$ which leaves me with $e^0=1$. It seems wrong, what have i done wrong here?

Comment: It seems to me like you have done
$$
e^{a+b} = e^a + e^b
$$
which is not correct. (You have used $a=\ln(1+y)$ and $b=\sin(xy)$)

Comment: $\exp(\ln(1+y)+\sin(xy))=(1+y)\exp(\sin(xy))$

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason to try to solve for y.  Implicit differentiation works nicely.

The original equation is $\ln(1+ y)+ \sin(xy)= \ln(5)$.   The derivative of y, with respect to x, is given by $\frac{y'}{1+ y}+ \cos(xy)(y+ xy')= 0$.

Note that when x= 0, $\ln(1+ y(0))+ \sin(0)= ln(5)$ so that $1+ y(0)= 5$ and $y(0)= 4$.  then $\frac{y'(0)}{5}+ \cos(0)(y(0)+ 0)= \frac{y'(0)}{5}+ 4= 0$.  So $y'(0)= -20$.

Using implicit differentiation again, $\frac{y''}{1+ y}- \frac{y'^2}{(1+ y)^2}- \sin(xy)(y+ xy')^2+ \cos(xy)(1+ y'+ xy'')= 0$.   Setting x= 0, $\frac{y''(0)}{1+ y(0)}- \frac{y'(0)^2}{(1+ y(0))^2}- \sin(0y(0))(y(0)+ 0)^2+ cos(0y(0))(1+ y'(0)+ 0y''(0))= \frac{y''(0)}{5}- \frac{400}{25}- 19= \frac{y''(0)}{5}- 3= 0$ so $y''(0)= 15$.

Answer (score 0):

Raising everything as a power of $e$ yields

$$e^{\ln(1+y)+\sin(xy)}=e^{\ln 5}\\
(1+y)\cdot e^{\sin(xy)}=5$$

Comment: so then it means that y=(5-e^sin(xy))/e^sin(xy). To go further should I substitute the sin(xy) with u or something? how do i finish the differentiation, do i need to do implicit differentiation?

Comment: Best I think to use implicit differentiation on the original equation, without trying to raise everything as a power of $e$. You will need to do this twice to solve the question so it's going to get complicated.

Comment: so i differentiate for y respect to x which is d^2y/dx^2 ? And then y''(0) i plug in x value as 0? but what happens if right hand side also has y in it? do i have to make it so all the y are on the left and all x is on the right to leave me with a function y?

Comment: No, the whole point of implicit differentiation is that it is a method of differentiating an expression as given, without first having to put $y$ on the left (only) and putting an expression in $x$ only on the right. To do this questijon you will first learn how to do implicit differentiation.

Comment: @JohnnyDang No offense, but it doesn't really look like you know what implicit differentiation is. At your current level of knowledge, attempting to solve the exercise is very likely to result in failure and frustration. In mathematics, you cannot go from crawling to running without first learning to walk. Before you can solve the exercise, you should go through what your textbook says about implicit differentiation.

Comment: The textbook says absolutely nothing remotely close to this problem. I know what implicit differentiation is, mister Einstein...

Comment: @JohnnyDang. If you know what implicit differentiation is, perhaps you could help us help you by starting this problem, showing us your steps and where you get stuck. As has been shown, your previous attempt was wrong.

Comment: @JohnnyDang You may know what implicit differentiation is or not, I don't know. But I do know that your comments and questions here show a fundamental lack of understanding of the topic, and my experience as a teacher tell me that it is that lack, not your ability to solve this particular question, that is the core of your troubles. As for the textbook, sure, it doesn't have *this* particular question, but it has others that will help you train up and build up your understanding on the topic.

Comment: @JohnnyDang As for your "mister Einstein" comment, if you think being snarky to people who are trying to give you good advice is a good idea, this again only shows that you still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

After composing with the exponential function, perform some elementary differential calculus: from $\:(1+y)\mathrm e^{\sin(xy)}=5$, you deduce instantly that
\begin{align}
\mathrm d\bigl((1+y)\,\mathrm e^{\sin(xy)}\bigr)&=\bigl((1+y)\,\mathrm e^{\sin(xy)}y\cos(xy)\bigr)\mathrm dx\\
&\phantom{=}+\bigl(\mathrm e^{\sin(xy)}+(1+y)\mathrm e^{\sin(xy)}x\cos(xy)\bigr)\mathrm dy.
\end{align}
Can you deduce $\;\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\:$ from there?